# bind two column into a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind two column from database into dropdownlist. Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(CommonRefference.Constr());
string query = "Select Id,Name+' ('+Distribution_name+') 'as Name1 from BR_supervisor  ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
con.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
        DropDownList3.DataSource = query;
        DropDownList3.DataTextField = "name1";
        DropDownList3.DataValueField = "Id";
        DropDownList3.DataBind();
}
con.Close();
```

But it gives the following error

> *DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'name1'*

How to do it? Anyone helps me is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its *Name1* not *name1*

change this to

```
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "Name1";
```

**EDIT:**

You are binding a string(query) to datasource here

```
DropDownList3.DataSource = query;
```

and string dont have a property with the name 'name1',so error

**SOLUTION :**

refer this,**I have changed this for your requirement**

```
private void LoadDropDownList()
        {
            SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(CommonRefference.Constr());
            string query = "Select Id,Name+' ('+Distribution_name+') 'as Name1 from BR_supervisor  ";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DropDownList3.DataSource = reader ;

            DropDownList3.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList3.DataTextField = "Name1";

            DropDownList3.DataBind();

            DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select One", "0")); // Adds items to the DDL
            DropDownList3.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("All Categories", "-1"));

            con.Close();
        }
```

For more explanation refer this link [Populate-ASP.NET-dropdownlist](http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?234737-Populate-ASP.NET-dropdownlist-through-Stored-Procedure-in-C)

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Name1'.

Comment: refer SOLUTION above,I have changed this for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
DropDownList3.DataSource = query;
```

You setting a string value as a source, so it tries to take a char value as an item for your drop down.

So, basically what you need is to create some kind of data source(List could be a good one), then fill it by mean of your reader, and then you can do something like the following:

```
DropDownList3.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: can u plz explain in details.i m new to asp.net

Comment: You probably should take a look into theese two articles, they will help you.
[datareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)
[dropdownlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)
Both of them have a good examples